# Modify mixer_paths.xml to use sepaker when headphones connected

Tags: android, audio, audio-streaming, audio-route, android-audio-streams

What should I edit in mixer_paths.xml to use internal speaker with headphones connected?
I want to use microphone from earphones and speaker from phone. Is this possible?

My mixer_paths.xml file content:

```
`https://pastebin.com/raw/Zc63Ejnu`
```

Its working via lesser audioswitch app but I want to do it without app. I have root acces to mixer_paths.xml.